# How is the null space related to singular value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

It is said that a matrix's null space can be derived from QR or SVD. I tried an example:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
1&3\\
1&2\\
1&-1\\
2&1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$ 
I'm convinced that QR (more precisely, the last two columns of Q) gives the null space:
$$Q= \begin{bmatrix} 
-0.37796&   -0.68252&   -0.17643&   -0.60015\\   
-0.37796&   -0.36401&   0.73034&   0.43731\\   
-0.37796&   0.59152&   0.43629&   -0.56293\\   
-0.75593&   0.22751&   -0.4951&   0.36288\\   
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
However, neither $U$ nor $V$ produced by SVD ($A=U\Sigma V^*$) make $A$ zero (I tested with 3 libraries: JAMA, EJML, and Commons):
$$ U= \begin{bmatrix} 
0.73039&   0.27429\\   
0.52378&   0.03187\\   
-0.09603&   -0.69536\\   
0.42775&   -0.66349\\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$ \Sigma= \begin{bmatrix} 
4.26745&   0\\   
0&   1.94651\\   
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$ V= \begin{bmatrix} 
0.47186&   -0.88167\\   
0.88167&   0.47186\\  
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
This is contradiction to

> Using the SVD, if $A=U\Sigma V^*$, then columns of $V^*$ corresponding to small singular values (i.e., small diagonal entries of $\Sigma$
>   ) make up the a basis for the null space.

Comment: The matrix you gave has full rank, so the dimension of the null space is zero. In general if you have a matrix of rank $r,$ the $\text{null}(A) = \langle v_{r+1}, v_{r+2}, \cdots, v_{n} \rangle.$

Comment: I see $rank(A)=2$. Now I wonder how to find a $2\times 4$ matrix $N$ from SVD to make $NA=0$.

Comment: You are asking for the row (left) null space which is different from the null space. The row (left) null space is generated by the rows of $U^T$ starting with row $r$ and continuing to the last row (assuming r is less than the height). This is of course assuming you take the _full_ svd and not the _reduced_ svd as you have done in your example. As for the QR, you can indeed choose to use it to find a basis for null space for the transpose of Q with columns corresponding to zeros in R.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Summary

Computing the full form of the singular value decomposition (SVD) will *generate a set of orthonormal basis vectors* for the null spaces $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$ and $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$.

### Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra

A matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ induces four fundamental subspaces. These are range and null spaces for both the column and the row spaces.
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

The singular value decomposition provides an orthonormal basis for the four fundamental subspaces.

### Singular Value Decomposition

Every nonzero matrix can be expressed as the matrix product
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{m}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The column vectors of $\mathbf{U}$ are an orthonormal span of $\mathbb{C}^{m}$ (column space), while  the column vectors of $\mathbf{V}$ are an orthonormal span of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ (row space).

The $\rho$ singular values are real and ordered (descending):
$$
  \sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \ge \dots \ge \sigma_{\rho}>0.
$$
These singular values for the diagonal matrix of singular values
$$
\mathbf{S} = \text{diagonal} (\sigma_{1},\sigma_{1},\dots,\sigma_{\rho}) \in\mathbb{R}^{\rho\times\rho}.
$$
The $\mathbf{S}$ matrix is embedded in the sabot matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ whose shape insures conformability.

Please note that the singular values *only* correspond to $\color{blue}{range}$ space vectors.

The column vectors form spans for the subspaces:
$$
\begin{align} 
% R A
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{u_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{u_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% R A*
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{v_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{v_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% N A*
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{u_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{u_{m}}
\right\} \\
% N A
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{v_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{v_{n}}
\right\} \\
%
\end{align}
$$

The conclusion is that the *full SVD provides an orthonormal span for not only the two null spaces, but also both range spaces.*

### Example

Since there is some misunderstanding in the original question, let's show the rough outlines of constructing the SVD.

From your data, we have $2$ singular values. Therefore the rank $\rho = 2$. From this, we know the form of the SVD:
$$
\mathbf{A} =
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \mathbf{S}  \\ \mathbf{0} \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
  \end{array} \right]  
$$
That is, the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$ is trivial.

*Construct the matrix* $\Sigma$:

Form the product matrix, and compute the eigenvalue spectrum
$$
 \lambda \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right) =
 \lambda \left( 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 6 \\
 6 & 15 \\
\end{array}
\right]
 \right) =
\left\{ 11 + 2 \sqrt{13},11-2 \sqrt{13} \right\}
$$
The singular values are the square roots of the ordered eigenvalues:
$$
  \sigma_{k} = \lambda_{k},\qquad k = 1, \rho
$$
Construct the diagonal matrix of singular values $\mathbf{S}$ and embed this into the sabot matrix $\Sigma$:
$$
\mathbf{S} =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{11 + 2 \sqrt{13}} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{13}} 
 \end{array}
\right], 
\qquad 
%
\Sigma =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{S} \\ \mathbf{0}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{11+2 \sqrt{13}} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{13}} \\\hline
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$

*Construct the matrix* $\mathbf{V}$:

Solve for the eigenvectors of the product matrix $\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A}$. They are
$$
v_{1} =
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{3} \left(-2+\sqrt{13} \right) \\ 1
\end{array}
\right]}, \qquad
v_{2}=
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{3} \left(-2-\sqrt{13} \right) \\ 1
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

The normalized form of these vectors will form the columns of $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$

$$
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
% v1
\frac{3}{\sqrt{26-4 \sqrt{13}}}
  \color{blue}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
   \frac{1}{3} \left(-2+\sqrt{13} \right) \\ 1
   \end{array} \right]}
% v2
\frac{3}{\sqrt{26+4 \sqrt{13}}}
  \color{blue}{\left[ \begin{array}{c}
   \frac{1}{3} \left(-2-\sqrt{13} \right) \\ 1
   \end{array} \right]}
\end{array}
%
\right]
$$
Because the null space $\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$ is trivial,
$$
 \mathbf{V} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
$$

*Construct the matrix* $\mathbf{U}$:

The thin SVD is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
% U 
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} 
% Sigma
  \mathbf{S} \,
% V 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
\end{align}
$$
which can be solved as
$$
\begin{align}
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} &= \mathbf{A} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} \mathbf{S}^{-1} \\
%%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{182 + 8\sqrt{13}}}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  7 + \sqrt{13} \\
  4 + \sqrt{13} \\
 -5 + \sqrt{13} \\
 -1 + 2 \sqrt{13} \\
\end{array}
\right]  }
&
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{182 - 8\sqrt{13}}}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  7 - \sqrt{13} \\
  4 - \sqrt{13} \\
 -5 - \sqrt{13} \\
 -1 - 2 \sqrt{13} \\
\end{array}
\right]  }
\end{array} \right]
%%
\end{align}
$$

The thin SVD is now complete. If you insist upon the full form of the SVD, we can **compute the two missing null space vectors** in $\mathbf{U}$ **using the Gram-Schmidt process**. One such result is
$$
\mathbf{U} =
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{182 + 8\sqrt{13}}}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  7 + \sqrt{13} \\
  4 + \sqrt{13} \\
 -5 + \sqrt{13} \\
 -1 + 2 \sqrt{13} \\
\end{array}
\right]  }
&
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{182 - 8\sqrt{13}}}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  7 - \sqrt{13} \\
  4 - \sqrt{13} \\
 -5 - \sqrt{13} \\
 -1 - 2 \sqrt{13} \\
\end{array}
\right]  }
&
\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  3 \\
 -4 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
\end{array}
\right]  }
&
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  3 \\
 -5 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]  }
%
\end{array} \right]
$$

### Conclusion

The singular values only interact with the first two range space vectors.

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \mathbf{S}  \\
     \mathbf{0} \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
&=
% U
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \color{blue}{\star} & \color{blue}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} \\
 \color{blue}{\star} & \color{blue}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} \\
 \color{blue}{\star} & \color{blue}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} \\
 \color{blue}{\star} & \color{blue}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} \\
\end{array}
\right]
% S
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sqrt{11+2 \sqrt{13}} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{11-2 \sqrt{13}} \\\hline
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% V
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \color{blue}{\star} & \color{blue}{\star} \\
 \color{blue}{\star} & \color{blue}{\star} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 9):

[The OP is answered, but I'd like to include a quick, to the point, reminder of sorts... or an observation on symmetries.]

---

**1. Left null space:**

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
1&3\\
1&2\\
1&-1\\
2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

In R statistical language,

```
A = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,2,-1,1), ncol = 2)
r = qr(A)$rank            # Rank 2
SVD.A = svd(A, nu = nrow(A)) 
SVD.A$u    # Extracting the matrix U from it...
```

$U=\begin{bmatrix}-0.73038560& -0.27428549& \color{blue}{-0.1764270}& \color{blue}{-0.6001482}\\
-0.52378089& -0.03187309&  \color{blue}{0.7303387}&  \color{blue}{0.4373135}\\
0.09603322&  0.69536411&  \color{blue}{0.4362937}& \color{blue}{-0.5629335}\\
-0.42774767&  0.66349102& \color{blue}{-0.4951027}&  \color{blue}{0.3628841}
\end{bmatrix}$

```
t.U.A = t(SVD.A$u)
(left_null = t.U.A[(r + 1):nrow(t.U.A),])
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.1764270 0.7303387  0.4362937 -0.4951027
[2,] -0.6001482 0.4373135 -0.5629335  0.3628841

colSums(left_null) %*% A
```

Therefore,

$\left[\alpha\begin{bmatrix}-0.1764270\\ 0.7303387\\  0.4362937\\ -0.4951027\end{bmatrix}^\top
+\beta\begin{bmatrix}-0.6001482\\ 0.4373135\\ -0.5629335\\  0.3628841\end{bmatrix}^\top\right]\; \begin{bmatrix} 
1&3\\
1&2\\
1&-1\\
2&1\\
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf 0$

with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being scalars.

---

**2. Right null space:**

Defining matrix $B$ as the transpose of $A$,

$B= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&2\\3&2&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

```
B = t(A)
r = qr(B)$rank  # Naturally it will also have rank 2.
SVD.B = svd(B, nv = ncol(B)) 
SVD.B$v    # Extracting the matrix V from it...
```

$V = \begin{bmatrix}-0.73038560& -0.27428549& \color{blue}{-0.1764270}& \color{blue}{-0.6001482}\\
-0.52378089& -0.03187309&  \color{blue}{0.7303387}&  \color{blue}{0.4373135}\\
0.09603322&  0.69536411&  \color{blue}{0.4362937}& \color{blue}{-0.5629335}\\
-0.42774767&  0.66349102& \color{blue}{-0.4951027}&  \color{blue}{0.3628841}
\end{bmatrix}$

```
(right_null = SVD.B$v[ ,(r + 1):ncol(B)])
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.1764270 -0.6001482
[2,]  0.7303387  0.4373135
[3,]  0.4362937 -0.5629335
[4,] -0.4951027  0.3628841

B %*% rowSums(right_null)
```

Therefore,

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&2\\3&2&-1&1\end{bmatrix}\;\left[\alpha\begin{bmatrix}-0.1764270\\ 0.7303387\\  0.4362937\\ -0.4951027\end{bmatrix}
+\beta\begin{bmatrix}-0.6001482\\ 0.4373135\\ -0.5629335\\  0.3628841\end{bmatrix}\right].$

---

```
In Matlab:

% Left null:

A = [1 3; 1 2; 1 -1; 2 1];
rank(A);
[U,S,V] = svd(A);
left_null_A = transpose(U);
rows = (rank(A) + 1): size(left_null_A,1);
left_null_A = left_null_A(rows,:)
(left_null_A(1,:) + left_null_A(2,:)) * A

% Right null:

B = transpose(A);
rank(B);
[U,S,V] = svd(B);
right_null_B = transpose(V);
rows = (rank(B) + 1): size(right_null_B,1);
right_null_B(rows,:)
right_null_B = transpose(right_null_B(rows,:))
B * (right_null_B(:,1) + right_null_B(:,2))
---

In Python:

Python:

# Left null:

import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[1,3], [1,2], [1, -1], [2,1]])
rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices = True)
t_U_A = np.transpose(U)
nrow = t_U_A.shape[0]
left_null_A = t_U_A[rank:nrow,:]
left_null_A
np.dot((left_null_A[0,:] + left_null_A[0,:]), A)

# Right null:

B = np.transpose(A)
rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(B)
U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(B, full_matrices = True)
t_V_B = np.transpose(V)
ncols = t_V_B.shape[1]
right_null_B = t_V_B[:,rank:ncols]
right_null_B
np.dot(B, (right_null_B[:,0] + right_null_B[:,1]))
```

Comment: cool! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

For an $m \times n$ matrix, where $m >= n$,
the "full" SVD is given by
$$
A = U\Sigma V^t
$$
where $U$ is an $m \times m$ matrix, $\Sigma$ is an
$m \times n$ matrix and $V$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.
You have calculated the "economical" version of the SVD
where $U$ is an $m \times n$ and $S$ is $n \times n$.
Thus, you have missed the information about the left null space
given by the "full" matrix $U$.
The full SVD is given by
$$
U =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
   -0.7304 &  -0.2743 &  -0.1764 &  -0.6001 \\
   -0.5238 &  -0.0319 &   0.7303 &   0.4373\\
    0.0960 &   0.6954 &   0.4363 &  -0.5629 \\
   -0.4277 &   0.6635 &  -0.4951 &   0.3629
\end{array}
\right],
$$

$$
\Sigma =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    4.2674   &      0 \\
         0   &  1.9465 \\
         0   &      0 \\
         0   &      0 
\end{array}
\right],
$$

$$
V =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
   -0.4719  &  0.8817 \\
   -0.8817  & -0.4719
\end{array}
\right].
$$
If you need the null spaces then you should use the "full" SVD. However, most problems do not require the "full" SVD.

Comment: Thanks! When a beginner succeeds in understanding something by chance, he sees a tip of iceberg.