# A question in SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, then SVD of A is $U\Sigma V^T$. I've seen different version of SVD. In the first one, $U\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In the second one $U\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$, and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$, where $r$ is the rank of $A$. Is there difference in these two forms or does one of them have an advantage over the other one? For instance when $U$ and $V$ are square matrices, then they are invertible, i.e, $U^TU=UU^T=I$. but when $U$ is not square only $U^TU=I$ is true.

Second question. if $A=U\Sigma V^T$, I've seen that $U^TU=I$. Can we deduce that $UU^T=I$, too?

Answer (score 1):

### First question

It follows from the definition of the SVD. The first one

$$ A_{m \times n} = U_{m \times m} \Sigma_{m \times n} V_{n \times n}^{T} \tag{1} $$

is the **full SVD**

the second one

$$ A_{m \times n} = U_{m \times r} \Sigma_{r \times r} V_{r \times n}^{T} \tag{2} $$

is the **truncated SVD** or **reduced SVD**  where $A$ has rank $r$

visually we see the difference

[image]

[image]

### Second question

It follows from the definition of the SVD. $U$ is orthogonal, which means that

$$ U^{T}U = UU^{T} = I \tag{3}  $$

### Note

In the SVD

$$ \sigma_{1} \geq \sigma_{2} \geq \cdots \sigma_{r} \geq 0 \tag{4} $$

if you multiply

$$ U_{m \times m} \cdot \Sigma_{m \times m} V_{m \times n}^{T}\tag{5} $$

and there are only $r$ singular values then it is $0$ after that. A diagonal matrix simply multiplies across. So we only care about

$$ U_{m \times r}\Sigma_{r \times r} V_{r \times n}^{T} \tag{6} $$

Comment: But if we write $U=[U_1 U_2]$, where $U_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times r}$ and $U_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times (m-r)}$, then $I_{m\times m}=UU^T=U_1U_1^T+U_2U_2^T$. Why $U_2U_2^T=0$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771013/null-space-from-svd

Comment: sorry that doesn't make sense...I think

Comment: it equals zero because the singular values are zero past the rank $r$

Comment: you have $U_{n} \Sigma _{n}  = 0 $

Comment: How is it related to $U_nU_n^T=0$?

Comment: I don't think your argument is true. As DiaryofNewton mentioned, $U_{m\times r}U_{m\times r}^T$ is not full rank, so it cannot be equal to $I_m$, as $I_m$ is full rank.

Comment: the rank of the matrix is $r$

Comment: the only matrix necessary is $U_{1}$

Comment: try making such a matrix...

Comment: some demonstration $U$ has full rank $A$ is rank deficient

Comment: Could you give argument rather than simulation?

Comment: turns out I was wrong, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Basically these two forms are equivalent. The second form can be deduced from the first form, whose elements are those of the second form and lots of zero, So when applied to data storage the second form take advantage, because you can ignore plenty of zeros and thus deal with a lower dimension.
Another thing is, if U is not a square matrix then the conclusion is not true. Take (0 1) as an example. Also you may consider the rank of UU' and U'U, one of whom can't be full-rank. But there's indeed a conclusion that they share the same nonzero egienvalues, including their dimension!

Comment: But Ryan claims that it is true.